# Prisma 2: How to paginate fields of a .findUnique() query?

Tags: graphql, prisma

[image]

**Description**:
I have a seeProfile resolver, which gives back a profile of a particular user.
This user has a photos array and I want to paginate these photos and I can't figure out how. I have a workaround but I'd like to know a way - shall it exist - to paginate a field of this one user.

**Workaround**:
I can simply make a resolver for fetching pictures for a particular user with **.findMany()** and paginate them with take: and skip: . But then I make two queries instead of one. So, if anyone knows a way to paginate the photos inside findUnique query, please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way as of now to implement pagination inside the `include` relation in Prisma.

You will have to make two separate queries with Prisma, as you described in your workaround:

1. One `findUnique` query to fetch the `user` records.
2. One `findMany` query to fetch the approrpriate `photo` records.

> I can simply make a resolver for fetching pictures for a particular user.

Perhaps it just makes sense to do both queries in the *same* resolver, to avoid two requests to the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will do it this way

Comment: Happy to help :D